# What are the drawbacks of assigning a new value to the elements you're using in a forEach loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say i have these 2 arrays:

```
let fruits = ["Big Yellow Banana", "Big Red Apple", "Small Red Cake"];
let adj = ["Big", "Red", "Cake", "Banana"]
```

I want to change the substring for each string in `fruits` that is found in  `adj` and replace it with `xxx`. For example, the resulting output should be:

```
["xxx Yellow xxx", "xxx xxx Apple", "Small xxx xxx"]
```

---

This is what I did:

```
let fruits = ["Big Yellow Banana", "Big Red Apple", "Small Red Cake"];
let myList = ["Big", "Red", "Cake", "Banana"];

fruits.forEach(function(part1, index1, theArray1) {
  myList.forEach(function(part2, index2, theArray2) {
    theArray1[index1] = theArray1[index1].replace(part2, "xxx");
  });
});
```

I'm concerned if assigning values back to the array via `theArray1[index1]` could cause any potential problem down the road. Let's say I'm not interested in keeping the original Array.

Comment: Let's say the biggest issue of your script is how good your client devices can handle large volumn of loops for each run ; )

Answer (score 2):

Modifying arrays can have unintended results. If the code above was its own function, it would be surprising to find my array has changed after calling that function. This is how bugs occur.

You can avoid these problems by simply creating a new array. Use `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` which return new entities, and avoid `Array#forEach` (which promotes side effects).

```
const redactedFruits = fruits.map((fruit) => {
  return myList.reduce(
    (redactedText, word) => redactedText.replace(word, 'xxx'),
    fruit,
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider use `map` as an alternative:

```js
let fruits = ["Big Yellow Banana", "Big Red Apple", "Small Red Cake"];
let myList = ["Big", "Red", "Cake", "Banana"];

// join the pattern with | and construct a regex with a global flag to replace all of them 
let regex = new RegExp(myList.join('|'), 'g');

console.log(
  fruits.map(fruit => fruit.replace(regex, 'xxx'))
);
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question.